# pexpect returning windows style end of line

Tags: python, pexpect

If anyone has used `pexpect` on linux have you notice that `pexpect` returns the window style end of line when using its `readline()` function? Do you know a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not only readline() that returns \r\n, all captured text returned by pexpect contains \r\n line endings.

The documentation has the following explanation:

> **readline(self, size=-1)**
>
> This reads and returns one entire line. A trailing newline is kept
>       in the string, but may be absent when a file ends with an incomplete
>       line. Note: This readline() looks for a \r\n pair even on UNIX
>       because this is what the pseudo tty device returns. So contrary to what
>       you may expect you will receive the newline as \r\n. An empty string
>       is returned when EOF is hit immediately. Currently, the size argument is
>       mostly ignored, so this behavior is not standard for a file-like
>       object. If size is 0 then an empty string is returned.

You can do something like this to convert \r\n to \n

```
line = child.readline()
line.replace('\r\n', '\n')
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`